# Undefined "Connection" during database pooling in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to pooling in node js. I am trying to start a pool connection at crud_new_op.js file and export the connection to db_crud.js and log it in the console.

I tried different ways but i always get "undefined" for the connection that i export from the pool...

**db_crud.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var crud = require('./routes/crud_op_new.js');

app.get('/search',(req,res)=>{
console.log(crud.connection);
});

app.listen(8044);
```

**crud_op_new.js**

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var conn = require('../config/db_config.js');

var db = conn.database;

var pool = mysql.createPool({
 connectionLimit : 100,
 host : db.host,
 user : db.user,
 password : db.password,
 database : db.database
});

pool.getConnection(function(err,connection){
 if(!err){
    exports.connection;
 }
 else {
    console.log("Error at pool creation");
 }
});
```

There i nothing wrong with database connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should return the connection

**db_crud.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var crud = require('./routes/crud_op_new.js');

app.get('/search',(req,res)=>{
 crud.connection(function (con) {
    console.log(con);
 });
});

app.listen(8044);
```

**crud_op_new.js**

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var conn = require('../config/db_config.js');

var db = conn.database;

var pool = mysql.createPool({
 connectionLimit : 100,
 host : db.host,
 user : db.user,
 password : db.password,
 database : db.database
});

exports.connection = function (callback) {
  pool.getConnection(function(err,con){
    if(err) throw err;
    return callback(con);
  });
}
```

Comment: `exports.connection()` will still return `undefined`

Comment: Nope. I have tried that. It will show connection object.

Comment: I am too getting same undefined

Comment: @digit, there is no `return` statement in your function which means i'll return `undefined`

Comment: Oh. I just notice that you don't initiate connection. Where do you call create pool in db_crud.js

Comment: Just add callback then .

Comment: You need not initialize at db_crud.js, as it has been created at crud_op_new.js. You have to import and use it thats it

Comment: Add callback ?? I dont get it. Can you edit the answer

Comment: Ok2. Its my mistakes. I thought it would return just that way. Let me update my answer.

Comment: Done. Can you try it?

Comment: Can you explain the "return callback(con)". How it works ... I dont understand it

Comment: Callback is an asynchronous equivalent for a function. A callback function is called at the completion of a given task. Node makes heavy use of callbacks. All the APIs of Node are written in such a way that they support callbacks

Comment: @user3649118, it makes no sense to return there with the `callback`. You can remove the `return` from it. It'll work the same.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just pass forward the `pool.getConnection` function?

```
// crud_op_new.js
exports.connection = pool.getConnection.bind(pool);

// db_crud.js
crud.connection(function (err, con) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(con);
});
```

Comment: This should be the simplest way without passing any callback.